# Finding local maximum between zero-values using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with minute-by-minute data from an IOT device. Every minute there is a new row with a timestamp and a value that represents a metric. The metric starts at 0 and increments for a while before it resets and starts over.

When I plot it, it looks like the picture. I want to find the local maximum value of each run, as the blue circles indicate.

Is it possible to find and group the consecutive rows where the metric is > 0 and then find the maximum of each group?

[image]

**Update**

Table structure:

```
+-------------+------------------+
| Field       | Type             |
+-------------+------------------+
| id          | int(10) unsigned |
| timestamp   | timestamp        |
| metric_name | varchar(32)      |
| value       | int(10)          |
+-------------+------------------+
```

Comment: Yes it is, but you will have to post your table structure .

Comment: @Octopi updated my question

Comment: nice one, what is the name of the table?

Comment: we can call it `metrics`

Comment: So find the max value (>0) every minute?

Comment: +1 for nice chart. Search for `gaps and islands` and how it is solved using MySQL possibilities. Most likely it will involve some clever use of variables. `island` is series of values >0, `gap` is series of values =0.

Answer (score 1):

This is based on the following assumptions:

1. Id is a perfectly sequential integer (with no gaps)
2. You want to get the value logged directly before the 0 value

Code:

```
SELECT *
  FROM metrics m1
 WHERE m.id IN (    
   SELECT m2.id - 1
     FROM metrics m2
    WHERE m1.value = 0)
```

Comment: Metric name is in the same table so there may be gaps based on that

Answer (score 0):

I join everything that isnt zero before a timestamp where it is zero, then I find the ones with no values inbetween that 0 and the last one..

```
SELECT  
    value,
    timestamp 
FROM
    metrics 
    LEFT JOIN metrics zeros
        on metrics.time < zeros.time
        and zeros.value = 0
    LEFT JOIN metrics betweenZero
        on metrics.time < betweenZero.time
        and betweenZero.time < zeros.time
    INNER JOIN metrics  noBetweens
        on table.id = noBetweens.id
        and betweenZero.id IS NULL
```

If you need it for a paritulcar `metric_name`, `WHERE metric_name = the_metric_name`on the end.

Comment: Tried it but no success, I only get 0's as a result. Also, I'm looking for the maximum value within each betweenZero time slot

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the max value per group along with start time and end time of each window with only 1 pass over the data.

```
select metric_name, max(value) value, max(start_group) start_time, max(end_group) end_time from(
select metric_name, value,
       case when @prev_ts is not null then @prev_ts end prev_ts,
       case when value = 0 then @ts := timestamp end as start_group,
       @ts as grouping,
       @prev_ts := timestamp end_group
from metric join (select @prev_ts := null as p) prev
order by timestamp
) q
group by metric_name, grouping;
```

This will create a sample data set of 1000 rows, that resets every minute.

```
insert into metric(timestamp, metric_name, value)
select now() - interval rn second, 'pressure', v
from(
    select @rn := @rn + 1 rn, mod(1000 - @rn,60) * pow(1000 - mod(@rn,121),1) v
    from   table_with_at_least_1000_rows
    join (select @rn := 0) rn
    limit 1000
) q
;
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution doesn't care about gaps but I am assuming that the sequence of `id`s is monotonic, that is they increase along the series by time. (You could probably substitute `id` for `timestamp` in the query even.) I had made a few minor syntax-type errors that I have since corrected since my first attempt and I have tested it with a simple Fiddle. I think it works.

```
select t0.*
from
    T t0 inner join
    (
        select max_z, max(id) as max_id, max(value) as local_max
        from
            (
            select
                id, value,
                (
                select max(t2.id) as max_id from T t2
                where t2.id < t.id and t2.value = 0
                ) as max_z
            from T t
            where t.value <> 0
            ) p /* partitions */
        group by p.max_z
    ) x /* extrema */
        on t0.id between max_z and max_id and t0.value = x.local_max
```

Btw it returns all the rows when there's a tie for the local maximum.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/de832/2

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
        T.min_id
        ,T.max_id
        ,MAX(M.value) as local_max
    FROM
        metrics M
        JOIN (
            SELECT
                    id as min_id
                    ,(
                        SELECT MIN(id) FROM Metrics MI
                            WHERE
                                MI.id > MO.id
                                AND MI.value = 0) as max_id

                FROM Metrics MO
                WHERE
                    value = 0
        )T ON M.id BETWEEN T.min_id AND T.max_id
    GROUP BY
        T.min_id, T.max_id
```